# PHP base64_encode failed and script terminated with blank page?

Tags: php, base64

I have an existing php script using base64_encode that works fine and then when i move this script into a new server it doesn't work, the script will just terminate with a blank page.

I tried to catch exception

```
try
        {
            $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
        }
        catch(Exception $ex) 
        {
            echo 'Message: ' . $ex->getMessage(); die;
        }
```

It still only shows a blank page. Any idea what caused this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
if(!function_exists('base64_encode')){
  echo 'base64_encode function not enabled';
}
if(!function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')){
  echo 'mcrypt not enabled';
}
```

to check if those needed functions are enabled.

Comment: Ok mcript is not enabled. Thanks!